# ng-repeat on a multi-dimensional array/object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting json object from an external url.

```
$http.get('http://dev-newsbackend.gotpantheon.com/articles')
  .success(function(data, status){

    $scope.articles = data.articles;

    console.log(data.articles);

  }).error(function(err){

       console.log(err);
  })  
})
```

The json I get is as below:

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "single": {
        "title": "7 Tech Upgrades to the Old-School Science Class"
      }
    },
    {
      "single": {
        "title": "What Will the ALS Association Do With That $100 Million?"
      }
    },
    {
      "single": {
        "title": "President Obama Rocked a Tan Suit, So Twitter Went Nuts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "view": {
    "name": "articles",
    "display": "page",
    "path": "articles",
    "root": "articles",
    "child": "single",
    "pages": 1,
    "page": 0,
    "count": 3,
    "limit": 10
  }
}
```

However, when I am doing a `ng-repeat` though the element is printed multiple times. Am not getting the value.

```
<ion-list  ng-repeat="article in articles">

    <ion-item>Test : {{ single.title }}</ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

**My developer console screen-shot:**
This is what I got for `console.log(data.articles);`

[image]

The screen-shot of my browser where am getting the list without the title value:

[image]

Comment: What is the error here?  It seems to be printing exactly what the code illustrates.  You're looping over the articles array and printing out the title.

Comment: if you see the actual title is not getting printed. {{single.title}} part is printing nothing. Only the hard coded value "Test:" is getting added for each line.

Comment: It should be `article.single.title`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ion-list  ng-repeat="article in articles">

    <ion-item>Test : {{article.single.title }}</ion-item>

</ion-list>
```